# How can I get a relative Uri for current controller action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use this UrlHelper extension method:

```
public static string ToPublicUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Uri relativeUri)
{
    var httpContext = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext;

    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
    {
           Host = httpContext.Request.Url.Host,
           Path = "/",
           Port = 80,
           Scheme = "http",
    };

    if (httpContext.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        uriBuilder.Port = httpContext.Request.Url.Port;
    }

    return new Uri(uriBuilder.Uri, relativeUri).AbsoluteUri;
}
```

This methd takes a relative Uri as a parameter. I am trying to call this method within a controller action and I cannot figure out how to get a relative Uri for the current Action

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the relative path based on a specific action name using:

```
urlHelper.Action("someActionName" /*, "someControllerName" */);
```

And you can get the *someActionName*, and *someControllerName* values for the current action using:

```
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["action"].RawValue
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["controller"].RawValue
```

Comment: Updated answer to answer the question more directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MakeRelativeUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx) method

```
Uri result= uriBuilder.Uri.MakeRelativeUri(relativeUri);
return result.ToString()
```

Comment: What am I passing into the MakeRelativeUri method as a param?